cmake equivalent for qmake's ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
I'm porting a project from Qt 5.15 to Qt 6.8.1 but I'm running into some problems.
In my app.pro file I have this line of code:
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$PWD/ssl/android/arm64-v8a/libcrypto.so $$PWD/ssl/android/arm64-v8a/libssl.so

I need to port this in cmake and I found this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-openssl-support.html
At some point it says:

Alternatively, to add extra libraries, such as libcrypto and libssl.
For CMake, use:
set_target_properties(<target_name> PROPERTIES QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
"<path_to_libs_dir>/libcrypto_3.so" "<path_to_libs_dir>/libssl_3.so" )
Or for qmake use:
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += <path_to_libs_dir>/libcrypto_3.so
<path_to_libs_dir>/libssl_3.so

That's exactly what I need but when I put this line in my CMakeLists.txt
set_target_properties(SamsungRC PROPERTIES
    QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS "ssl/android/arm64-v8a/libcrypto.so" "ssl/android/arm64-v8a/libssl.so"
)

I get this error:
CMakeLists.txt:72: error: set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?
Thank you in advance

The documentation is definitely wrong: the command set_target_properties accepts a single value for a property, not an array of values. Probably, the property QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS is treated as a CMake list, where elements are separated with semicolon. In that case pass "ssl/android/arm64-v8a/libcrypto.so;ssl/android/arm64-v8a/libssl.so". Also, most likely the property is interpreted as containing absolute paths, not relative ones. Use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} for refer to the directory with the currently processed CMakeLists.txt.

I'm interpreting the linked documentation in the same way. Looking at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html though (is that the CMake version you're using?) it doesn't compute. The two paths should be the value for QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS, but that would require putting them into a list/tuple/array (no clue what CMake uses) instead. If that works, please file a bug ticket, so the faulty docs get fixed!

maybe: https://github.com/a12e/docker-qt?tab=readme-ov-file#notes

@Tsyvarev your solution works, thank you! You can add the comment as answer so I can mark it as resolved!
